# Undeclared identifier when including MVTec Halcon libraries

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2013, x86

I have a problem configuring Visual Studio.

I have to integrate the MVTec Halcon library in a C++ VS2013 project made by someone else which is based on Qt 5.5 x86

I created a small VS2013 Project starting from a VisualC++ empty project, then I added the directories for the includes and the relative libs. Everything works fine.

I made sure that all the project properties are the same between the "test" project and the actual project but when I insert the line of code

```
#include "HalconCpp.h"
```

the project won't compile anymore. I get a long list of "undeclared identifier" pointing to other halcon header files. It looks like it's including a bunch of external headers except the one that contains the definitions needed by the others.

For example "HTuple.h" contains

```
  eTupleTypeEmpty = UNDEF_PAR,
```

but "UNDEF_PAR" is defined in "Hbase.h" which apparently is not included

I checked and checked again if the two configurations are the same because it really looks like there must be a typo somewhere but I can't find it.

What else could it be? Where do I look?

Thank you